# Tree list with all database columns

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm looking at the [Tree Behavior](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html#getting-formatted-tree-lists) in CakePHP 4.

How does one get all database columns when getting a representation of the tree using `treeList`? Example:

```
$treeList = $this->Tasks->find('treeList')
```

At this time, all I can think of is looping the list, fetching individual records and pushing to an array?

```
$tasks = [];

foreach($treeList as $key => $value)
{
    array_push($tasks, $this->Tasks->get($key));
}
```

Comment: Is this not just [finding threaded data](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-threaded-data), linked from just above where your link leads?

Comment: @GregSchmidt OMG! TIL. Yes, this is exactly what I needed. I figured there was a better way. And, sigh, I skimmed over this too fast it seems. I'll upvote your answer if you provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `threaded` option in find:

```
find('threaded')
```